# Paired barplots

Tags: r, bar-chart, histogram

so I am very new to R and really do not know what I am doing.  Ive tried looking through tutorials but am just really confused.  I am trying to create a barplot that will compare two predictor variables with multiple response variables
My predictor variables are random and nest.  I have 6 response variables.   ex. tree density, ground cover, canopy cover, max veg height, etc.  Can anyone help me figure out how to do this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please provide some more details? For example, I think it would be helpful if you show us a sample of the data for your barplot.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data, all necessary code, and a clear explanation of what you're trying to do and what hasn't worked.